# Rewrite on a masked subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, domain-masking

I have a `CNAME` entry that adds a domain mask to an external site.

The `CNAME` masking maps to `member.mydomain.com` on my domain.

At `member.mydomain.com` there is a subfolder I would like to rewrite.

So the question is how do I rewrite `member.mydomain.com/subfolder` to `mydomain.com/subfolder`?

I have tried many variations with absolutely no luck. I am wondering if this is an issue because it is targeting a masked domain.

Any direction anyone could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^member\.(mydomain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(subfolder)(/.*|)$ http://%1/$1$2 [NC,R=301,L]
```